# Regex to match spaces before comma but not after

Tags: html, regex, text

I would like to have a regex that will not allow spaces AFTER comma but spaces before comma should be allowed. **The comma should also be optional.**

My current regex:

```
^[\w,]+$
```

I have tried to add `\s` in it and also tried `^[\w ,]+$` but that allows spaces after comma as well!

This should be the test case:

```
Hello World // true
Hello, World // false (space after comma)
Hello,World // true
Hello,World World // false
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 'Not allow' is ambiguous what did you mean specifically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below regex won't allow space after a comma,

```
^[\w ]+(?:,[^ ]+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/8)

**Explanation:**

- `^` start of a line.
- `[\w ]` Matches a word charcter or a space one or more times.
- `(?:)` This is called non-capturing groups. Anything inside this group won't be catched.
- `(?:,[^ ]+)?` A comma followed by any character not of space one or more times. By adding `?` after the non-capturing group, this tells the regex engine that it would be an optional one.
- `$` End of a line

Comment: Perfect! Please add an explination :)

Comment: @imbondbaby The Regex101 demo has an explanation of the regex.

Comment: Sorry, not near a PC... and Regex101 wants me to update my browser before viewing their website.

Comment: @imbondbaby added explanation.

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj. I was trying to figure out this problem for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
^[\w ]+(?:,\S+)?$
```

**Explanation**:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
[\w ]+     # any character of: word characters, ' ' (1 or more times)
(?:        # group, but do not capture (optional):
  ,        #   ','
  \S+      #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
)?         # end of grouping
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: It needs to allow spaces before the comma, so yours won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends what you want to do, if you are just testing for the presence of the grammar error, you can use something like.

[See this example here >](http://regex101.com/r/rS7gJ8/1)

```
var patt = / ,/g; // or /\s,/g if you want
var str = 'Hello ,World ,World';
var str2 = 'Hello, World, World';
console.log( patt.test(str) ) // True, there are space before commas
console.log( patt.test(str2) ) // False, the string is OK!
```

Lookaheads are useful but can be hard to understand without knowing the basics.

[Use this site](http://regex101.com/), it is great for visualising your Regex